# Confused when using Python logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I want to log to 2 different files, but different things.

I was trying this:

```
runid = str(uuid.uuid1())
logger = logging.getLogger('logger1')
other_logger = logging.getLogger('logger2')

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

debug_handler = logging.FileHandler('log/debug.log')
info_handler = logging.FileHandler('log/info.log')
other_handler = logging.FileHandler('log/other_info.log')

debug_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
other_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter(runid + ' - %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s')
debug_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
info_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
other_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(debug_handler)
logger.addHandler(info_handler)
other_logger.addHandler(other_handler)

logger.info('message1')
other_logger.info('message2')
```

But logger and other_logger are working as one and I get both messages in all files, no matter if I call in logger or other_logger.

According doc:

> "Loggers have the following attributes and methods. Note that Loggers
>   are never instantiated directly, but always through the module-level
>   function logging.getLogger(name). Multiple calls to getLogger() with
>   the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger
>   object."

But the parent object is always the same, as in this small test:

```
import logging

log1 = logging.getLogger('hey')
log2 = logging.getLogger('you')

print log1.parent, log2.parent

enrique@enrique-mbp:$ python /tmp/test.py 
<logging.RootLogger object at 0x26f0810> <logging.RootLogger object at 0x26f0810>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This code works just fine for me -- I get see only `message1` in the `logger` files and only `message2` in the `other_logger` files. Regarding the same parents in `hey` and `you`, that's the correct behavior; the common parent is just the root logger, as is shown. However, the individual loggers will indeed be different.

Comment: This seems to be a typo for `setLevel` (`other_handler.set_name(logging.INFO)`), but correcting it provides the expected behavior.

Comment: @santon: did you test it? WIthout the changes I mentioned in my answer below, the code does _not_ work properly.

Comment: @jakegriffin: Yeah, I made those modifications you mentioned in your answer. But those changes don't really affect the issue stated in the question, which is that the messages are being passed to both loggers.

Comment: @santon: Yes, I suppose that's true. It seems that a lot of questions on this site have a different issue than the asker expects.. which is why they have to ask. I just wouldn't have stated that the code "works just fine" without mentioning that you had to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

You need to set the level for `other_logger` as well:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
other_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # or INFO because that is the lowest level being used by a handler
```

Without this, other_logger remains at the default logging level, `logging.WARNING`, which prevents the `other_logger.info('message2')` line from logging anything.